# Clockwork for Heroku scheduled task is causing NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, scheduled-tasks, nameerror

This is my first time using the Ruby on Rails 'clockwork' library. I'm getting the following error when my scheduled job tries to execute:

```
ERROR -- : uninitialized constant Delayed (NameError)
```

Here's the code in the job causing the error:

```
every(1.day, 'Queueing scheduled job', :at => '22:40') { Delayed::Job.enqueue ScheduledJob.new }
```

I followed Heroku's guide for using 'clockwork' (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby), but I'm not entirely sure how the scheduled job is supposed to know what task to execute? Does it know simply because the task itself resides in 'lib/tasks'?

My n00bie gut tells me that the NameError that 'Delayed' is causing is where I should identify the task to run.

Any insight into this would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you still have that problem. Do you have gem 'delayed_job_active_record' in your Gemfile?. Have you followed the installation step from here:https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/